# Getting "field has incomplete type" even after adding forward reference

Tags: c++

I'm still just learning c++ and trying sort out how to have two c++ classes store instance variables of each-other. I realize that you've got to add a forward reference to do this, but I think I must still be missing something here.

```
class B;

class A {
public:
  B b;
};

class B {
public:
  A a;
};
```

Trying to compile this gives the error:

```
temp.cpp:5:5: error: field 'b' has incomplete type
   B b;
     ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a type as member, the type must complete. In your case, you want to use B,A inside each other which is not possible.

But you could use pointer to resolve the issue:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
  B* b;  // now b is a pointer which points to B type, incomplete type B is OK
};
```

**§ 3.9.5 Types**

> A class that has been declared but not defined, or an array of unknown size or of incomplete element type, is an incompletely-defined object type.43 Incompletely-defined object types and the void types are incomplete types (3.9.1). **Objects shall not be defined to have an incomplete type.**

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. This is an infinite recursion: an instance of A has to include an instance (not a pointer!) of B, and an instance of B has to include an instance of A.